# Custom shader in URP not upgradable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I was using a custom shader in 2018 Unity version where there was LWRP and now I have upgraded to the latest Unity with URP and I no longer can use this shader. It is all pink. I have even tried to go to settings and upgraded project materials, yet it throws an error `There's no upgrader to convert Custom/OnTop shader to selected pipeline`. How can I reuse this shader in URP?

```
Shader "Custom/OnTop" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    [NoScaleOffset] _EmissionMap ("Emission", 2D) = "black" {}
        //_Emission ("Emission", Color) = (0, 0, 0)
        [HDR] _EmissionColor ("Emission Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
}
SubShader {
           Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
 
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    LOD 200
    ZWrite Off 
    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade

    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;
    sampler2D _EmissionMap;
    fixed4 _EmissionColor;

    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        // put more per-instance properties here
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
         o.Emission = tex2D(_EmissionMap, IN.uv_MainTex) * _EmissionColor;
                
                 c.rgb += o.Emission.rgb;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
[NoScaleOffset] _EmissionMap ("Emission", 2D) = "black" {}
//_Emission ("Emission", Color) = (0, 0, 0)
[HDR] _EmissionColor ("Emission Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
```

to

```
_EmissionMap ("Emission", 2D) = "black" {}
//_Emission ("Emission", Color) = (0, 0, 0)
_EmissionColor ("Emission Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
```